# how to call variables within sed command

Tags: shell-script, sed, variable

I want to get count of number of records in last 1 hour

my code is below

```
nowdate=$(date +'%H:%M:')
pastdate=$(date +'%H:%M:' -d "1 hour ago")

echo $nowdate
echo $pastdate

sed -rne '/"'"$pastdate"'"/,/"'"$nowdate"'"/p' /data/recvdmsg.log | wc -l
```

output I am getting is,

```
12:47:
11:47:
0
```

Furthermore This works fine with predefined values like this

```
sed -rne '/00:00:/,/00:59:/p' /data/recvdmsg.log | wc -l
```

I want to call my  `$nowdate`, `$pastdate` variable within the sed command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put in your statement way too many quotes. It should work just fine like this:

```
sed -rne "/$pastdate/,/$nowdate/p" /data/recvdmsg.log | wc -l
```

Or this way if you still want to use single quotes:

```
sed -rne '/'$pastdate'/,/'$nowdate'/p' /data/recvdmsg.log | wc -l
```

Keep in mind, that in case there is `/` character in your variable it will break `sed` expression.

---

If you want to filter these records further, you can do that in Sed rather than adding grep on the end:

```
sed -rne "/$pastdate/,/$nowdate/ { /pattern-to-grep-for/p; }" /data/recvdmsg.log
```

(Spaces are for readability; they aren't mandatory.)

Comment: Thanks,it works fine. bdw can i add grep command with this in order to  filter some records .

Comment: @Prabash see edit.

Answer (score 1):

While this is a general comment rather than a specific answer, I am posting as an answer because it may help OP with the underlying problem of seeing what is wrong with the expansion.

When you are composing arguments which rely on expansion, and you want to know what the expanded argument will look like, then just `echo` it.

If you at the look at the output from

```
echo '/"'"$pastdate"'"/,/"'"$nowdate"'"/p'
/"12:36:"/,/"13:36:"/p
```

Then you can see the problem is the quotation